# Help identifying a rose?

Tags: roses

We bought a rose we love about two years ago in US zone 10a (California Bay Area) and lost the tag, and have been searching online trying to identify the variety-- and thought one of the experts here might have an idea. It has almost no scent, and here are a few photos of a bloom, buds, and its habit.

The only other thing my wife remembers is it's not a David Austen style, because that's the style she usually buys and she remembers this one being different. Thanks for any tips, ideas, or resources... or requests for other information or photos that would help..

I read a few articles about using the "everyrose" database, but that web site seems to be down currently.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a Pat Austin rose?

Comment: Do I see right, no thorns?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Oh, I think you are right, there aren't any thorns from what I can see.

Comment: @giacomocatenazzi there are some thorns but very few, I can get a better photo of that. And thanks for the idea, Rob-- though we didn't think it was a Pat Austin partly because it has almost no scent and we've read Pat Austens do (and we believe we remember when buying it that it wasn't in the David Austen category).

Comment: @calibex Try smelling the bud of a newly blossoming rose during mid morning. If there is in fact no sent than I wouldn't be supersized if it was some type of tea rose.